# Android apps with Microsoft Graph and B2C directory

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I came across the tutorial Android App with Microsoft Graph https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-android which builds an Android app that uses the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve calendar information for a user. In one of the exercise steps one need to register the app in the Active Directory in the Azure portal. Will this Android App also work with a B2C tenant?

Comment: Thanks @Waldulmer and please refer this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal/integrate-aad-b2c-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It also works with a B2C tenant.

What I mean is that you can configure the Android APP with the app registration in the B2C tenant and get the calendar information for the B2C Work account users whose mailboxes are hosted in O365.

It doesn't work for consumer accounts because consumer accounts' mailboxes is not hosted in O365.

Refer to [Overview of user accounts in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview) to learn about the differences between work accounts and consumer accounts.